# How can i shuffle array in LAMDA Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using simple lamda function to return the array but i need to shuffle it so every time it will change the sequence properly.

```
dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
    }
    else{

        console.log(data);
        const items = data.Items.map(
            (dataField) => {
                return {
                    rather:dataField.Rather.S, 
                    would:dataField.Would.S, 
                    wouldClick:+dataField.wouldClick.N, 
                    ratherClick:+dataField.ratherClick.N,
                    QuestionID:dataField.QuestionID.S, 


                };
            }    
        );
        callback(null, items);

    }

});
```

As you see in call back sites returning items I need to shuffle this item so every time sequence will not same and it will shuffle properly

items are formating like this

```
[
  {
    "rather": "asd",
    "would": "dsa",
    "wouldClick": 4,
    "ratherClick": 2,
    "QuestionID": "f70da742-6731-48f4-84aa-a15c68e26cdf"
  },
  {
    "rather": "asda",
    "would": "ssam",
    "wouldClick": 4,
    "ratherClick": 1,
    "QuestionID": "de23902c-87ef-4a80-afd7-2f9b5bb0724d"
  },
  {
    "rather": "sada",
    "would": "asdk",
    "wouldClick": 2,
    "ratherClick": 3,
    "QuestionID": "7d57a847-b7e6-4e87-a9a4-abfe2a2d85ad"
  }
]
```

Working like this

```
const shuffleitems = shuffle(items);
callback(null, shuffleitems);

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Obvious but incorrect way**

You can implement random sorting in this way

```js
const aa = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
const sortedRandomly = aa.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
```

In your case try implement your code like this

```js
const items = data.Items.map(
            (dataField) => {
                return {
                    rather:dataField.Rather.S, 
                    would:dataField.Would.S, 
                    wouldClick:+dataField.wouldClick.N, 
                    ratherClick:+dataField.ratherClick.N,
                    QuestionID:dataField.QuestionID.S, 


                };
            }    
        ).sort(() => Math.random() - .5);
```

This approach is simple and obvious but it is incorrect since it doesn't generate a uniform distribution, you can find detailed information [here](https://javascript.info/task/shuffle).

**Correct way of implementation**

Better way is implement [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Example of implementation in javascript:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}
```

So author's case could be resolved in this way:

```js
const items = shuffle(data.Items.map(...));
```

Comment: That doesn't generate a uniform distribution, and it's also not a valid way to use sort (its callback must return a number with the same sign each time it's called with the same args, it can't be independent of its arguments)

Comment: Use fisher-yates for shuffling

Comment: @Paul any example how can i do in this function?

Comment: This code solves author's problem - it shuffles array randomly in simplest way. I agree about argument independency but author needs the way how to sort array randomly and i provided it. Try it, it works

Comment: Unless they specify a different distribution, it is pretty safe to assume that when someone wants something randomly generated, they also want a uniform distribution.

Comment: @ShahnazRaheem Search for "Fisher-Yates JavaScript". There are plenty of examples out there. Then you just need to use it like `shuffle( items )` where `shuffle` is some implementation of Fisher-Yates

Comment: @Paul thanks find something in end of my question i attached the working function its working fine. This is  fisher-yates  ?

Comment: Yes, that looks like a good Fisher-Yates shuffle. It should be noted that it shuffles the array you give it in-place, so after: `const shuffleitems = shuffle(items);`, items and shuffleitems are both the same array and both shuffled. I.E. You could change your two lines to `shuffle( items ); callback( null, items );` and it would work the same.

Comment: I have investigated this topic and enhanced my answer with Fisher-Yates algorithm implementation